# I can't update windows 8 to 8.1 under virtual box on my macbook pro

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, cpu

I installed windows 8 on my macbook pro under virtualbox. Now I want to update it to 8.1 with the store (free), but I get the error:

```
You can't update because this doesn't support de CPU of your PC.
```

Processor Information:

```
Processorname:  Intel Core i7
Processorspeed: 2,5 GHz
```

Does anyone knows a fix for this?

Comment: You can't the CPU requirements slightly changed with the 8.1 release, more information on the CPU, to explain why exactly

Comment: **The processor information is specific enough.**  There are about 10 2.5 Ghz i7 SKUs on the market today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the VM, go into VirtualBox's settings and on the *General* page, on the *Basic* tab, change the *Version* from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 (ensure you select the appropriate Bit level).

Save the settings and start the VM.

[Source (VirtualBox forums)](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=58364)

Comment: Awesome! Windows 8.1 is downloading atm.